# syntax error with string values

Tags: code

i tried  below code :

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_view')->getvalofk('Mark');
```

i get result but when i call it dynamically like

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_view')->getvalofk('.$_REQUEST["id"].');
```

or

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_view')->getvalofk("'.$_REQUEST["id"].'");
```

i am doing some syntax mistake. what am i misisng here ?....

```
 public function getvalofk($code)
    {
        $_option = array(
            'Blush Opaque'  => array(
                'option' => array(
                    'Turquoise',
                    'Pearl',
                    'Lapis'
                ),
                'price' => 0

            )

            ,
            'Blush Vitreous'  => array(
                'option' => array(
                    'Peridot',
                    'Amethyst',
                    'Blue Topaz',
                    'Smoky Quartz',
                    'Citrine'
                ),
                'price' => 0
            ),
           );

        return $_option[$code];
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no need from quotes, just:

```
$helper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_view')->getvalofk($_REQUEST["id"]);
```

Comment: not working as value is string

Comment: What is the code of the function getvalofk? Please paste it. What is the error?

Comment: check?.. ne error just blank value

Comment: yeah working just some other error

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do. But maybe we have to check before the return: if (isset($_option[$code])) { return $_option[$code]; } else { return array(); }